# Customize CalendarView in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, calendarview

As I can change the color of a specific date or leave a permanent selection on the calendar, the idea is to distinguish it from the other dates.

```
private CalendarView calendarView;
calendarView=findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
calendarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```